# PHP - Looping through a QueryString

Tags: php, loops, foreach, query-string

Trying to loop through a querystring in php but only getting last value. What should I be doing to get all values?

example:
querystring = ?style=ranch&style=barn&style=colonial

php:

```
$sqlStyle = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as count  FROM houses_single ";
$i = 1;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($i == 1){
        $sqlStyle .= "where ";
     }else{
        $sqlStyle .= " and ";
    }
    $sqlStyle .=  $key . " like '%" . $value ."%'";
    $i++;
 }
 echo $sqlStyle;
```

Result:
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as count  FROM houses_single Where Houses like '%colonial%'

Comment: style needs to be an array in your HTML form to pass multiple values with key style

Comment: A house can be ranch AND barn AND colonial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameter "style" is an array in this case and must be identified by square brackets - if not, the last key=value pair will overwrite the others.

```
?style[]=ranch&style[]=barn&style[]=colonial
```

`$_GET['style']` is an array then you can loop over by using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_GET['style'] as $value) {
    // ...
}
```

if 'style' is not the only parameter you want to add, you can use a `is_array()` check in the `foreach` loop:

```
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($i == 1){
            $sqlStyle .= "where ";
         }else{
            $sqlStyle .= " and ";
         }

         if(is_array($value)) {
             $sec = array();
             foreach($value as $second_level) {
                 $sec[] =  $key . " LIKE '%" . $second_level."%'";
             }
             $sqlStyle .= implode(' AND ', $sec);
         }
         else {
            $sqlStyle .=  $key . " LIKE '%" . $value ."%'";
         }

         $i++;
     }
     echo $sqlStyle;
```

alternative without foreach:

```
<?php

$statement = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as count FROM `houses_single`";

if(is_array($_GET)) {
   $statement .= ' WHERE';

   // create copy to keep the $_GET array
   $add_where = $_GET;

   array_walk(function($elem,$key){
      is_array($elem) {
         return implode(' AND ', array_map(function($sec) using ($key)  {
             return "$key LIKE '%$sec%'";
         }, $elem);
      }
      else {
            return "$key LIKE '%$elem%'";
      }
   },$add_where);

   $statement .= implode(' AND ', $add_where);
}
```

*(codes are untested)*

Sidenode about safety: I hope you won't use this code snippet you provided in productive environment without any escaping of the parameters.

Comment: how do i loop through the querystring then? and I know WHY you say not to do that in production, but HOW do I do that?

Comment: Updated the answer, hope this fits your needs. For security take a look at [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)